# ScriptEngine is returned null

Tags: java, java-17

I have recently upgraded my lambda function to java17

and i am facing issue with below code

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

here i am getting engine as null

i have added the gradle dependency for nashorn

implementation 'org.openjdk.nashorn:nashorn-core:15.0' as Nashorn engine is removed from java 17

but still test cases are failing as engine is returned null
not sure if I am missing something here.

Can someone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `getEngineByName("nashorn")`? Or test whether the engine is on the classpath/modulepath via `Class.forName("org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory")`

Comment: Hi @Holger thanks for your comment, i changed the engine itself to manager.getEngineByName("graal.js") and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected as java 17 no longer supports the Nashorn engine as you said.
however to run js code you can instead use `org.mozilla`
I have this code exemple that might help you

```
 import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
 import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
 import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;

 public class JSValidator   {
    public boolean validateJs( String script) {

    Context context = Context.enter();
    try {
        Scriptable scope = context.initStandardObjects();
        Function function = (Function) context.compileFunction(scope, 
        script, "JS_OUTPUT:", 1, null);
        Object result = function.call(context, scope, scope, new Object[] 
        {"",""});
        if (result instanceof Boolean booleanResult) {
            return (Boolean) result;
        } else {
            throw new ApiException();
        }
    } finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
  }
```

you can find more detail on mozilla web site( [www.mozilla.org](http://www.mozilla.org) )

Answer (score 0):

My ide worked with embedded java and `engine returns null`. I added the jdk 1.8 to eclipse, added it to the project and everything worked for me.

It might be useful.